# Insert before the last occurrence of a specific character in a string in PHP

Tags: php

I would like to insert something before the last occurrence of a specific character in a string.

In the below case replace the last occurrence of `<p>` with `Hello <p>`

```
$tdr="<p>Previous reports stated that the Pokemon Alpha.</p><p>On the other hand, Pokemon Diamond and Pearl are reported .</p><p>On the other hand, Pokemon Diamond and Pearl are reported.</p>";

$newtdr= "<p>Previous reports stated that the Pokemon Alpha.</p><p>On the other hand, Pokemon Diamond and Pearl are reported .</p> Hello <p>On the other hand, Pokemon Diamond and Pearl are reported.</p>";
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am trying to learn how to use lastindexof in php, but I can't find a comparable function.

Comment: it's html. you don't deal with html with string functions or regexes, unless you are 100% SURE that the format will never change. you use [DOM](http://php.net/dom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use a regular expression with negative lookahead:

```
print preg_replace("~<p>(?!.*<p>)~", "Hello $0", $tdr);
```

If you like string functions more, try [`strrpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php):

```
 $n = strrpos($tdr, '<p>');
 print substr($tdr, 0, $n)  . ' Hello ' . substr($tdr, $n);
```

Comment: Both of them replaced the first occurrence of <p> with Hello <p>. I'm trying to replace the last occurrence of <p> in the string.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. I guess I made a small mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
$tdr="<p>Previous reports stated that the Pokemon Alpha.</p><p>On the other hand, Pokemon Diamond and Pearl are reported .</p><p>On the other hand, Pokemon Diamond and Pearl are reported.</p>";

$pos = strrpos($tdr, '<p>');

$newtdr = substr($tdr,0,$pos) . ' Hello ' . substr($tdr, $pos);

echo $newtdr;
```

That should sort it.

If you're desperate to do it as a replace use the following:

```
$newtdr = substr($tdr,0,$pos) . ' Hello <p>' . substr($tdr, $pos + 3);
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to be replacing the last occurrence, does it?

Comment: No, as it had the potential to break the HTML code.  I've edited my answer to include the replace variant too.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `explode()` function you can split apart a string into an array based on a delimiter. Then I've taken the last element of the array, prepended "Hello" to the string, and used implode to put it back together!

```
$tdr="<p>Previous reports stated that the Pokemon Alpha.</p><p>On the other hand, Pokemon Diamond and Pearl are reported .</p><p>On the other hand, Pokemon Diamond and Pearl are reported.</p>";
$ex = explode("<p>", $tdr);


$new = "Hello." . $ex[3];

$finished = implode("<p>", array($ex[1], $ex[2], $new));

var_dump($finished);
```